# onchange event not working for jQuery auto complete combo box

Tags: ajax, jsp, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i am using ajax to get details from  database as in this [Example](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/comboSelect.shtml) along with it
i used jquery autocomplete combo as in this [Example](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html).

The combo box works fine **without the auto complete**.
When the auto complete is active the details are not generated in the `onChange Event` of the combo box.

```
<select name="sitemCode" id="itemCode" onchange="showItem(this.value)">  
<option value = " 0 ">Select Item Code</option>
```

How can i make it work with the autocomplete jquery ? Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this ??

```
   $('#itemCode').change(function() {
    var itemCode= $("#itemCode option:selected").text();
    showItem(itemCode);
    });
```